# AngularJS : How use $http in a filter

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do a request to my backend in a filter and return the result of my request.
The problem is the service $http return a promise and it's the issue.

For present the issue I used a $timeout and the promises of angular in my fiddle : 
[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flavien69/Kdeaa/)

In my filter I use a $timeout with a promise but the final goal is to use a request http :

```
myApp.filter('filterHello', function ($http,$timeout,$q) {
return function (company_id) {
    console.log("in the filter");
    var deferred = $q.defer();   
    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("ca marche");
    }, 2000);                  
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

});

Then in my view I use my filter who is suppose to display "ca marche" with a delay of 2 secondes but that doesn't work :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{hello|filterHello}}
</div>
```

You can see that the filter return nothing and that there is an infinite loop in the filter because of the null promise I think.

If you don't understand why I want use a request http in a filter the answer is simple.
For exemple I have an object user with the fields : email,name,company_id..
And I have an other object company with the fields : name, createOn,... 
I would like use the filter like this for display the name of the user's company :

{{user.company_id | ShowNameCompany}}

So, I need to do a request http in the filter to my company controller of my backend.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Post the code that you tried please

Comment: Filters fire a LOT! There must a more bandwidth friendly method of achieving your goal.

Comment: The fiddle link is not showing because it has a `[2]:` in front of it.  And further, on SO, you can't post a link to jsfiddle.net without also adding some code to your question.  Please add some code and make sure the link is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the end goal here? Why are you using $http in filters in the first place?

Comment: Yes sorry I fixed the link for the fiddle. Mike I agree with you but if I use the cache for my request I will do only one request and then get the data in the cache

Comment: I just update my post where I explain my goal.

Comment: Your update makes it sound like you should create a directive, not a filter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should not use filters that way. Filters are for transforming inputs based on optional params.

The problem here would be that you're immediately returning a promise from the filter function. And that's nothing Angular can deal with as a result from a filter.

My suggestion therefore would be this - fetch the result first, work with the filter based on the result:

```
var app = angular.module("my.module");

app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$http', '$scope', function(http, scope) {
  scope.hello = "foo";
  http.get('http://my.service.com').then(function(data) {
    scope.filterParams = data;
  }, function(err) {
    scope.filterParams = undefined;
  });
}]);

app.filter("filterHello", function() {
  return function(input, params) {
    if(typeof params === "undefined") {
      return "";
    }
    //work with the params here
  };
});
```

and in the Template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{hello|filterHello:filterParams}}
</div>
```

Edit: Just read your explanation. To me, this would be a candidate for a directive:

```
app.directive("companyName", ['$http', function(http) {
  return {
    template: "<span>{{name}}</span>",
    scope: {
      companyId: "="
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      http.get("http://my.service.com/companies/" + scope.id).then(function(result) {
        scope.name = result.name;
      }, function(err) {
        scope.name = "unknown";
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

and in the template:

```
<span company-name company-id="user.company_id"></span>
```

If you have a lot of companies, you should preload the names (maybe send them with the first response initially?), as you'd be bombarding your server  quite a bit with requests.

Comment: Hey Florian. It is a good idea to make a directive the problem is that I use a request http for get the user so in my directive the scope companyId is undefined. I need to wait that the user is load but I don't know how... That make sense??

Comment: I just fix this issue using ng-if="user.company_id" like this angular execute the directive when the user is load.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a stateful filter:

```
    angular.module("app").filter('companyName', function($http) {
        var cached = {};
        var apiUrl = 'http://my.service.com';
        function companyNameFilter(company_id) {
            if (company_id) {
                if (company_id in cached) {
                    // avoid returning a promise!
                    return typeof cached[company_id].then !== 'function' ?
                        cached[company_id] : undefined;
                } else {
                    cached[company_id] = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: apiUrl + company_id
                    }).success(function (companyName) {
                            cached[company_id] = companyName;
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        companyNameFilter.$stateful = true;
        return companyNameFilter;
})
```

and use it like so: `{{company_id | companyName}}`

Beware: The function companyNameFilter will be called on **each digest cycle**.

Also, you would need to figure out a way to reset the cache if it grows too big.

See: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/async-angular-filter/

And the plunker (the link above won't display it, so here's a direct link): http://plnkr.co/edit/EK2TYI1NZevojOFDpaOG?p=preview

Comment: this is work only in a view by mentioned construction like `{{company_id | companyName}}`, however use this custom filter in a controller?
In controller construction like `console.log('ctrl Filter:', $filter('companyName')($scope.company_id));` did not work!
Maybe someone could fix it also for other use, not only in a view.
best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you must make an http request within a filter as I also found a reason to recently, then do it as shown below.

Note that the Angular team discourages the use of stateful filters as I quote from their documentation

> It is strongly discouraged to write filters that are stateful, because the execution of those can't be optimized by Angular, which
>   often leads to performance issues. Many stateful filters can be
>   converted into stateless filters just by exposing the hidden state as
>   a model and turning it into an argument for the filter.
>
> If you however do need to write a stateful filter, you have to mark
>   the filter as $stateful, which means that it will be executed one or
>   more times during the each $digest cycle.[Stateful filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#stateful-filters)

Going by this recommendation, here is what you should do:

1. Declare your filter so that it accepts a scope object as it's first parameter:
   function filter($http) {

   ```
   return function (cached, type, productField) {
           var key = type + '-' + productField;
           var oDataFilter = 'Id eq \'' + productField + '\'';
           var select = 'Id,Name';
           if (typeof cached[key] == 'undefined') {
               $http({
                   url: '//<endpoint>/resource.json?$select=' + select + '&$filter=' + oDataFilter 
                   , method: 'GET'
                   , headers: {
                       Accept: 'application/json'
                   }
               }).then(function (data) {
                   cached[key] = data.data.d.length > 0 ? data.data.d[0].Name : 'Not found';
               });
               cached[key] = 'Loading...';
           }
           return cached[key];
       }
   }
   filter.$inject = ['$http'];
   app.filter('myFilter', filter);
   ```
2. Define a variable that will be available within the scope of your template. I'll call mine **filterCache** and assign and empty object **{}** to it.
3. Invoke the filter from inside of your template like this:

   ```
   <div ng-bind-template="{{filterCache|myFilter:firstParameter:secondParameter}}"></div>
   ```