# Create an angular filter that returns remote data?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have a snippet of code that I use very often, that calls an API in order to return a user name based on an ID sent over to it.

```
 GetUserNames.get({users: user}, function (data) {
                $scope.userName = data[0];
             })
```

What I would like to do is turn this into a filter where I can do something like

```
{{userID | returnUserName}}
```

so that I can reuse and keep my controllers and my views clean. I wrote something like this:

```
angular.module('app.filters').filter('returnUserName', function(GetUserNames) {
    return function(input) {
      GetUserNames.get({ users: input }, function (data) {
          console.log(data[0])
          return data[0]

      }); 
     }
});
```

and while console.log is returning the correct value, I dont see it on the page. I'm guessing this is a timing issue. Is there anything I can do to make this work, so that the value is then populated on the page?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think that what you need is a directive, not a filter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864318/angular-how-use-http-in-a-filter

Comment: That is not what filters are meant for. They are used for formatting essentially

Comment: That's factory code, not filter. Set cache to true and will be available immediately after first call without needing to make request for every controller that needs it. Also where are you returning to in the callback? Nowhere. your outer function returns nothing

Answer (score 3):

> I have a snippet of code that I use very often

Whenever you hear yourself saying that think **services** not filters. While you *could* in theory have your filter make remote calls, it is a gross misuse of filters and will probably be very inefficient (likely causing your page to be slow and possibly even DDoSing your server).

Your patterns should look more like

```
{{ returnUserName(userId) }}
```

Or perhaps even pre-computer the username somewhere and then just do

```
{{ userName }}
```

Comment: that top one looks very clean--- I havent used services in that way before. Can I call my resource factory (GetUserNames) from the factory?

Comment: @Ortal You can use it anywhere, just list it as a dependency

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question , here's a snippet of code that should answer your question.
If you use Angular 1.3.X, you can use $stateful like :

```
angular.module('app.filters').filter('returnUserName', function($http) {
  var data = null, serviceInvoked = false;

  function realFilter(value) {
      return data;
  }

  filterStub.$stateful = true;
  function filterStub(value) {
    if( data === null ) {
        if( !serviceInvoked ) {
            serviceInvoked = true;
            $http.get('/url/test/').then(function (res) {
                data = res;
            });
        }
        return "";
    }
    else return realFilter(value);
  }
   return filterStub;
});
```

For more information : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046641/asynchronously-initialize-angularjs-filter)

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Florian Orpeliere mentioned, you could use a stateful filter - and additionally use some cache variable:

```
    angular.module("app").filter('svcData', function($http) {
        var cached = {};
        var apiUrl = 'http://my.service.com';
        function svcDataFilter(data_id, data_prop) {
            if (data_id) {
                if (data_id in cached) {
                    // avoid returning a promise!
                    return typeof cached[data_id].then !== 'function' ?
                        cached[data_id][data_prop] : undefined;
                } else {
                    cached[data_id] = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: apiUrl + data_id
                    }).success(function (data) {
                            cached[data_id] = data;
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        svcDataFilterFilter.$stateful = true;
        return svcDataFilterFilter;
})
```

and use it like so: `{{data_id |svcData:'property'}}`

Beware: The function svcDataFilter will be called on **each digest cycle**.

Also, you would need to figure out a way to reset the cache if it grows too big.

See: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/async-angular-filter/

And the plunker (the link above won't display it, so here's a direct link): http://plnkr.co/edit/EK2TYI1NZevojOFDpaOG?p=preview