# How do I handle promises inside a filter?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a filter that converts money to another currency, for example Japanese Yen to USD and I want it to be as simple as:

```
{{ myMoneyInYen | usd }}
```

My problem is, I am fetching the values used for conversion from an API, but I can't seem to make it work. It's just blank. It would have been really nice if I could that. You guys think I should turn it into a directive instead?

```
module.filter('svcData', ['promisedSvc', function(promisedSvc) {
  return function(input) {

    promisedSvc.then(function(svc) {
      var valuesUsedForConversion = svc.getData(input);
      //DO actual conversion here.
      return convertedValue;
    });


  };
}]);
```

Comment: filter needs to be synchronous.

Comment: scratch that, I'll just turn it to a directive. :\

Comment: This may help. Essentially filters should work on data by either performing a set task, or with optional params. You should first fetch your data and pass it in. Either through your service or directly through optional params. you controller could init data in your service wich your filters requests. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864318/angular-how-use-http-in-a-filter#answer-19865072, EDIT Christ my grammar was bad there sorry.

Comment: can still use filter .. just preload the conversions

Comment: @ste2425 I didn't want to use that approach, because then I will have to fetch the data for every controller that needs it. I was kinda hoping the custom filter can do that for me. If I had to change something, I just change the filter. At least that's what I think D:

Comment: @charlietfl I'll try that

Comment: @Petra You do not need to do it for every controller if that logic is extracted out of the controller which it should be. Depending if its a single page app or not it could be at a higher level than your `ng-view` if not it could be in a service where your controller calls a method to initialize it. The service stores that and only inits it once. your filters then just request that initialized data from your service. If its at load time you could also put it in the `.config()` but not too sure if ajax calls can be made then.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set the resulting data into a scope accessible variable when resolving your promise, and filter this variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stateful filter:

```
    angular.module("app").filter('svcData', function($http) {
        var cached = {};
        var apiUrl = 'http://my.service.com';
        function svcDataFilter(data_id, data_prop) {
            if (data_id) {
                if (data_id in cached) {
                    // avoid returning a promise!
                    return typeof cached[data_id].then !== 'function' ?
                        cached[data_id][data_prop] : undefined;
                } else {
                    cached[data_id] = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: apiUrl + data_id
                    }).success(function (data) {
                            cached[data_id] = data;
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        svcDataFilterFilter.$stateful = true;
        return svcDataFilterFilter;
})
```

and use it like so: `{{data_id |svcData:'property'}}`

Beware: The function svcDataFilter will be called on **each digest cycle**.

Also, you would need to figure out a way to reset the cache if it grows too big.

See: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/async-angular-filter/

And the plunker (the link above won't display it, so here's a direct link): http://plnkr.co/edit/EK2TYI1NZevojOFDpaOG?p=preview